# Bundling SDL2, SDL_image with my application

Tags: c++, sdl

I'm working with a simple SDL2 application in C++11 and i'm curious about bundling the required libraries with my application. Right now, i need SDL2, SDL_image and libpng to be installed on the machine. However, what if the user does not have the libraries installed? Can i somehow bundle the libs with my application? Is this possible?

I'm using Cmake to build.

Answer (score 3):

You can either ship the libraries as dynamic-linked libraries (`.DLL` files on windows, `.so` on linux, `.dylib` on OSX) along with your application, or you can compile your application with static linking, which will copy the contents of the libraries you're using into the application.

Comment: How can i statically link with Cmake?